# The previous instances of usercontrol have the same values with last one. Why?

Tags: user-controls, instance

In my application (winForm - using devexpress components), I have tabs with the same `UserControl` (with different values when Control Loading depending on User choice) into them.

My problem is that all `userControl` instances have the same values as the last instance.

Why this happening ?

Code in visual Rpg.

(when user clicks the button to create new user control)

```
BEGSR manageCreateNew
    DCLSRPARM sender Type(*Object)
    DCLSRPARM e Type(DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs)

    DCLFLD appCode Type(*String)
    DCLFLD fileStatusParm Type(*Boolean)
    DCLFLD parmCompany Type(*Char) Len(3)
    DCLFLD parmProtNo Type(*Zoned) Len(5,0)
    DCLFLD parmProtYear Type(*Zoned) Len(2,0)
    DCLFLD TabForm1 Type(KYKLADES_Menu_Protocol.ManageProtocol)
    DCLFLD TabFormSupplier Type(KYKLADES_Menu_Supplier.SupplierForm)
    DCLFLD infoBoxResult Type(DialogResult)
    DCLFLD IsProjectSubHeaderOpen Type(*Boolean) Inz(*True)
    DCLFLD supplierCodeParm Type(*String)
    DCLFLD isView Type(*Boolean)
    DCLFLD isOldVsl Type(*String) Inz(" ")

    Try
        manageCreate = "Create" + appCode
        IsProjectSubHeaderOpen = CheckIfProjectSubHeaderCOpen(IsProjectSubHeaderOpen)
        if IsProjectSubHeaderOpen = *False

            barbuttonItem_Save.Enabled = *True
            barbuttonItem_Close.Enabled = *True
            barButtonItem_New.Enabled = *False
            barButtonItem_Edit.Enabled = *False
            barButtonItem_Delete.Enabled = *False

            appCode = %SubSt(tabControlSubCategory.SelectedTabPage.Tag.ToString().Trim(), 1, 3)
            projectOption = %SubSt(tabControlSubCategory.SelectedTabPage.Tag.ToString().Trim(), 4, 3)

            if projectOption = '005'
                fileStatusParm = *True
                selectionParm = *True
                parmCompany = *Blanks
                parmProtNo = *Zeros
                parmProtYear = *Zeros
                isView = *False
                isSaved = *False
                TabForm1 = *new KYKLADES_Menu_Protocol.ManageProtocol(fileStatusParm,parmCompany,parmProtNo,parmProtYear,isOldVsl,isView)
                WITH TabForm1
                .Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
                ENDWITH
                tabPageSubCategoryHeader = *new DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabPage()
                WITH tabPageSubCategoryHeader
                    .ImageIndex = FileLibrary.APPIMG //Image
                    .Name = projectOption + "manageCreate"
                    .Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
                    .Size = *new System.Drawing.Size(525I, 343I)
                    .Text = "Create Protocol"
                    .Tag = "manageCreate"
                    .Controls.Add(TabForm1 *As Control)
                ENDWITH

                tagString = "Create"+appCode

            endIf
```

It's my first time of using VS for your info. I think that when user change the tab (in this point) have to get the right instance of user control ? is this correct ?

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution for my problem.

For your info iam using ASNA Visual RPG 14 for visual studio 2015.

The problem had to do with deceleration of object and the use of SHARED parameter.

From ASNA newsletter.

Terminology confusion
Be aware that AVR and VB use Shared to indicate that a variable is owned by a class, as opposed to non-shared members which are owned by class instances. AVR and VB also both use Static to indicate that a variable’s value persists across routine calls.

Thanks